# How emacs take present file as argument to a function automatically?

Tags: shell, emacs

I am making my own shell command. What is the command that automatically takes the present file as argument of a function when i press enter (just like % in .vimrc file. basically i want that interactive command should invoke automatically when i don't pass any argument as filename while calling the function and automatically takes the present file as the input to the command.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understood your question, you may be looking for the variant of `interactive` with a lisp form that produces the arguments:

```
(defun echo-current-buffer-filename (f)
  (interactive (list (buffer-file-name)))
  (message "Current buffer filename is %s" f))
```

See the documentation of the `interactive` function at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html for more information.